# cannot convert argument of incomplete type 'void *' to 'const bitData'

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to create a bit array in c++ and it works when I create a single variable. But I can't figure out how to fix this error when I am trying to create an array out of it.

```
typedef struct bitData
{
      unsigned bit:1;
} bitData;

int main() {
  bitData* buff;
  *buff = malloc(3 * sizeof(struct bitData));
  buff[0].bit = 1;
  buff[1].bit = 0;
  buff[2].bit = 1;

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  {
    printf("buff[%d] = %d\n",i , buff[i].bit);
  }
}
```

Here is the error :

```
$ g++ main.cpp 
main.cpp:23:9: error: no viable overloaded '='
  *buff = malloc(3* sizeof(struct bitData));
  ~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:12:16: note: candidate function (the implicit copy assignment operator) not viable: cannot convert argument of incomplete type 'void *' to 'const bitData'
typedef struct bitData
          ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: buff = malloc and not *buff = malloc

Comment: You should decide whether you want to program C or C++.

Comment: `buff = static_cast<bitData*>(malloc(3 * sizeof(struct bitData)));`

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant .. I tried that but it give `error: assigning to 'bitData *' from incompatible type 'void *'`

Comment: @krzaq .. your suggestion is working ... thanks

Comment: Note that this is probably the most inefficient way to have an array of bits. Instead of `malloc`, you should look for `std::vector`, and for array of bits `std::vector<bool>` specifically. What you are doing now is writing C style code in C++, which is far from ideal.

Comment: Note that each one of your `bitData` is the size of an `unsigned int`, most likely 32 bits.

Comment: @molbdnilo .. Ok .. so i wanted size to be 1 bit .

Comment: @molecule Nothing can be smaller than a `char`. There are numerous articles and tutorials online about manipulating bits.

Comment: Remember about freeing the memory after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*buff` is an lvalue of type `bitData`. You can't assign a pointer to it.

In C, you can just say this:

```
buff = malloc(3* sizeof(struct bitData));
```

In C++ you cannot directly assign a `void*` to `T*`, you need to cast it:

```
buff = static_cast<bitData*>(malloc(3* sizeof(struct bitData)));
```

Although if you're using C++ you should use `new` rather than `malloc`, or, even better, containers/smart pointers to avoid manually managing memory.

If you want this part of code compatible with both C and C++, use C-style cast (be sure you really need to do this, though):

```
buff = (bitData*)malloc(3* sizeof(struct bitData));
```

Comment: Then follow @user694733's advice. `vector<bool>` mayb be exactly what you want. What you're doing here is allocating 3 bytes, for 3 structs, even if you only use 1 bit of each.

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo in your code. The `*` in front of your pointer variable needs to go, you don't want to dereference it here, you want to assign to it.

In C:

```
int main() {
  bitData* buff;
  buff = malloc(3 * sizeof(struct bitData));
```

In a horrible C/C++ hybrid:

```
int main() {
  bitData* buff;
  buff = (bitData*)malloc(3 * sizeof(struct bitData));
```

In C++:

```
int main() {
  bitData* buff = new bitData[3];
```

Comment: That's still not valid C++ without a cast

Comment: yeah .. although you are right but that is still not valid

Comment: @krzaq That's why I asked him whether this is supposed to be C or C++... [In C you don't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: @nvoigt the question text says C++, tags say C++ and C. So it's ambiguous but rather C++.

Comment: @krzaq Well, the code itself is plain C. But I expanded my answer to contain other options.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the code as below and try:

```
typedef struct bitData
{
      unsigned bit:1;
} bitData;

int main() {
  bitData* buff;
  buff = (bitData*)malloc(3 * sizeof(struct bitData));
  buff[0].bit = 1;
  buff[1].bit = 0;
  buff[2].bit = 1;

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  {
    printf("buff[%d] = %d\n",i , buff[i].bit);
  }
}
```

Remove the `*` before `buff` and typecast it while allocating the memory. The above code will get compiled without any error or warning.